# Calling a PHP script from jQuery using Ajax to create a new folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a file manager running on a Linux server based on jQuery. This code is contained in the file script.js.
There is also a tiny index.php which includes the script.

I added a button to the index.php and implemented its listener to the script. By pressing this button I want the listener to call a php script (createfolder.php) which creates a new folder in the current path.

Here are the relevant codes of the different files.

**index.php**

```
<body>

<div class="filemanager">

    <div class="search">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Find a file.." />
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="createFolder">create folder</button>

    <div class="breadcrumbs"></div>

    <ul class="data"></ul>

    <div class="nothingfound">
        <div class="nofiles"></div>
        <span>No files here.</span>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Include our script files -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

**script.js**

```
        $( "button" ).click(function() {

    //just a test to see if the listener and the variable works
    alert('test1: currentPath= ' + currentPath);


                    function callCreateFolderPhp() {

                    //also just a test
                    alert('test2');

                    $.ajax({

                    url: "createfolder.php",                        
                    type: "GET",
                    data: "curPath=" + currentPath,

                    success: function(msg){
                        //more testing
                        alert("test3");
                    }

                    });

                    //another one
                    alert('test4');

                }

    callCreateFolderPhp();

    //final test
    alert('test5');

    });
```

**createfolder.php**

```
<?php
$currentPath = $_GET['curPath'];
//different ways I have tested
mkdir($currentPath+'/newfolder/', 0700);
mkdir($currentPath+'/newfolder1', 0700);
mkdir("newfolder2");
?>
```

If I click the button I receive my test alerts as well as the proper path but the new folder won't be created.

Where did I make a mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Does the folder that will house the folder you are creating have the proper write permissions?

Comment: How can I check and change permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new directory with 744 write permissions.

```
mkdir ($currentPath . '/newfolder/', 0744);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the update. The (.) period operator is used to combine strings, which is what you need. Sorry, php is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

I added a few statements.

```
<?php
$currentPath = $_GET['curPath'];
//different ways I have tested
mkdir($currentPath+'/newfolder/', 0744);
mkdir($currentPath+'/newfolder1', 0744);
mkdir("newfolder3", 0744);
mkdir($currentPath+'/newfolder/newfolder/', 0744);
mkdir($currentPath+'/newfolder1/newfolder1', 0744);
mkdir($currentPath+'newfolder/', 0744);
mkdir($currentPath+'newfolder2', 0744);
mkdir($currentPath+'/newfolder/newfolder4/', 0744);
mkdir($currentPath+'/newfolder1/newfolder4', 0744);
?>
```

The only line that works is

```
mkdir("newfolder3", 0744);
```

But I want to use it with the currentPath variable. Is there a way to check what's $currentPath is assigned with? In the script.js currentPath looks like this files/place

Comment: Have you tried to echo $currentPath? Your problem is probably that you aren't passing $_GET['curPath'] in your GET form method.

Comment: It says http://domain/createfolder.php?curPath=files

The path is now files. Shouldn't it be /files? This one doesn't work either:

mkdir('/' + $currentPath + '/newfolder/', 0744);

Comment: Actually none. It's just not working. My editor even says that this mkdir('/' + $currentPath + '/newfolder/', 0744); is not allowed.